# How to query all the points inside a geomtry object of wkt format

Tags: python, postgresql, postgis

i have a table named `slope` it contains the following columns `X`, `Y`, `Z` and `geometry`. the aforementioned values represents the x,y,z coordinates
of a geometry. i have also an object named `fieldGeometry` which is in WKT format.
my question is how can i query the all the points in terms of `X`, `Y` that are inside the object `fieldGeometry`.

as shown in the code below, it is my attempts but not successful.
please let me know how to query all the points inside a geometry object in wkt format

**code**:

```
def executeWithFetchallForST_Intersects(self, cursor, fieldAsPolygonsGeometry, gridPointsAsGeometry):
    #"SELECT ST_Intersects("+ fieldAsPolygonsGeometry + "," + gridPointsAsGeometry + ")"
    cursor.execute("SELECT ST_Intersects("+ fieldAsPolygonsGeometry + "," + gridPointsAsGeometry + ") FROM " + config['PostgreDB']['table_name'])
    return cursor.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0):

The PostGIS function is called [`ST_Contains`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Contains.html). To check if the `x`,`y`,`z` coordinates are inside of the polygon on `fieldGeometry` just do:

```
SELECT 
  ST_Contains(fieldGeometry,
  ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(x,y,z),4326)) 
FROM slope;
```

Demo: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c103fe80408c564371f332740a9951a4)

```
CREATE TABLE slope (x numeric, y numeric, z numeric, fieldGeometry geometry(polygon,4326));
INSERT INTO slope VALUES 
(-4.6726,54.1180,42,'SRID=4326;POLYGON((-4.52 54.32,-4.38 54.32,-4.38 54.26,-4.52 54.26,-4.52 54.32))'),
(-4.5449,54.1888,42,'SRID=4326;POLYGON((-4.59 54.21,-4.49 54.21,-4.49 54.17,-4.59 54.17,-4.59 54.21))');
```

[image]

```
SELECT 
  ST_Contains(fieldGeometry,
  ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(x,y,z),4326)) 
FROM slope;

 st_contains 
-------------
 f
 t
(2 rows)
```

**EDIT**: see comments

PostGIS tries to parse the geometries using known formats, such as WKT, WKB, GeoJSON, etc. So you don't need to worry about using WKT in the `ST_Contains` function - no matter which programming language you're using, e.g.

```
WITH j (p) AS ( VALUES
 ('0101000000925CFE43FA2D12C00EBE30992A184B40'),
 ('POINT(-4.5449 54.1888)'),
 ('{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-4.5449,54.1888]}')
)
SELECT 
  ST_Contains('POLYGON((-4.59 54.21,-4.49 54.21,-4.49 54.17,-4.59 54.17,-4.59 54.21))',p) 
FROM j;

 st_contains 
-------------
 t
 t
 t
(3 rows)
```

If you wanna force PostGIS to parse a specific format, let's say WKT, use the corresponding function [`ST_GeomFromText`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html).

Comment: thank you for your time and effort. but i would like to tell you that, as stated in the question, the `fieldGeometry`is an object not a strting. do you think it will be valid to pass it as an object to the st_contains()??

Comment: would you please show me how to pass the geometry object `fieldGeometry` to the select stataement.i will use the select statement in python. should it be as follwos:def executeWithFetchallForST_Contains(self, cursor, fieldAsPolygonsGeometry):
        cursor.execute("SELECT ST_Contains(" + fieldAsPolygonsGeometry + "," + ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(x,y,z),4326) + ") FROM " + config['PostgreDB']['table_name'])
        return cursor.fetchall()